# How to sort (order) WordPress playlist by metadata (such as artist, album, bitrate etc.)?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, metadata, playlist

I can use WordPress in-built orderby to sort playlist by `title` or any column in `wp_posts` table, as shown below.

```
    echo wp_playlist_shortcode( array(
                        'ids' => '7,8,9',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => 'title', 
    ));
```

But how to sort playlist **by attachment metadata** (such as Album, Artist, Bitrate, Length, Year, File Size etc.)?